# Good Resources for Making Custom Artwork for a Non-Artist?

Tags: dnd-5e, dungeons-and-dragons, homebrew, art

I like to employ PowerPoint in my adventures with my party (Eberron right now!). I feel, as the DM, like it provides a "taste" of the world to my players and helps springboard their imaginations along common lines and visualize the world for them.

Does anyone know of any good programs/websites where I can create some "custom" artwork of sorts? I'm not looking to make fancy oil paintings. Just throw together some neat looking portraits.

I use Dungeon Painter Studio for my maps. That's the kind of resource I'm looking for to make custom pics for my illustrations. Something where I can "place a building here" or "place a prop/character there", "set the background to be this", etc.

Any ideas?